# How Do I Configure Automatic Updates in WordPress 3.7?

Tags: automatic-updates

WordPress 3.7 added automatic updates. How does this work, and how can I configure this feature?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Automatic updates are automatic.

The basic, default behavior in WordPress 3.7 is automatic update of core for minor versions (i.e. `X.Y.Z` to `X.Y.Z+1`.)

No configuration options are exposed in the UI. To change the behavior, you'll need to modify your `wp-config.php` file, or add some filters:

### Easy Disabling

Add the following to `wp_config.php`:

```
define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );
```

Alternatively, add the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'automatic_updater_disabled', '__return_true' );
```

### Core Update Control

Via `wp-config.php`:

```
// Update core - development, major, and minor versions
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', true );

// Update core - minor versions
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', 'minor' );

// Core update disabled
define( 'WP_AUTO_UPDATE_CORE', false );
```

Via filters:

```
// Enable nightlies (dev updates):
add_filter( 'allow_dev_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );

// Enable major version updates:
add_filter( 'allow_major_auto_core_updates', '__return_true' );

// Disable minor updates
add_filter( 'allow_minor_auto_core_updates', '__return_false' );
```

### Themes and Plugins

All-or-Nothing Auto-Update Themes and Plugins:

Theme and Plugin updates are **disabled** by default. To enable via filter:

```
add_filter( 'auto_update_plugin', '__return_true' );
add_filter( 'auto_update_theme', '__return_true' );
```

These filters are passed to the update object; so it is possible to manipulate that object to target specific Themes or Plugins to be updated, either to whitelist (include) or exclude from automatic updates.

### Translation Files

Translation file updates are **enabled** by default. To disable via filter:

```
// Disable translation updates
add_filter( 'auto_update_translation', '__return_false' );
```

### Update Result Emails

The updater sends a result email on success, failure, or critical error. To disable via filter:

```
// Disable update emails
add_filter( 'auto_core_update_send_email', '__return_false' );
```

This filter can also be used to manipulate update emails according to email `$type` (success, fail, critical), update type object `$core_update`, or `$result`:

```
/* @param bool   $send        Whether to send the email. Default true.
 * @param string $type        The type of email to send.
 *                            Can be one of 'success', 'fail', 'critical'.
 * @param object $core_update The update offer that was attempted.
 * @param mixed  $result      The result for the core update. Can be WP_Error.
 */
apply_filters( 'auto_core_update_send_email', true, $type, $core_update, $result );
```

### Further Reading

Codex entry [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Disabling_Automatic_Background_Updates). More information [here](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/10/25/the-definitive-guide-to-disabling-auto-updates-in-wordpress-3-7/).

Comment: Is there a way I can test if my automatic updates are working besides waiting? Also can I exclude certain plugins from the update plugin filter?

Comment: Enable nightlies and then wait until tomorrow? :) And no, there's currently no way to include/exclude certain Plugins or Themes; it's all-or-nothing.

Comment: I think you can do this for individual theme/plugin update as per Nacin's comments "The previous configuration options are all-or-nothing. You may, however, want something more fine-grained. The `auto_update_$type filter (auto_update_core, auto_update_plugin, auto_update_theme, auto_update_translation)` is fired for specific updates, as they are ready to be updated. This filter is passed the actual update object that describes what WordPress is about to update. This means you can selectively enable individual plugins or themes to update, for example, or whitelist upcoming core updates."

Comment: @pollyplummer by all means, please add that info to the answer! That's good stuff. :)

Comment: In the section "Easy Update", shouldn't it be "**Or** add the following filter"?

Comment: @brasofilo "*In the section "Easy Update", shouldn't it be "Or add the following filter"?*" - not according to the Codex. It recommends using both.

Comment: If I'm following the core logic correctly, it passes [first](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L1736) by the filter, [then](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php#L1748) by the constant. If so, we should update the Codex entry with "or". I'm also seeing that `DISALLOW_FILE_MODS` halts any kind of update.

Comment: Updated blanket disabling to reflect Codex change. Updated Theme/Plugin to indicate targeted filtering. Added section for disabling/manipulating update result emails.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I just posted a guide for [how to exclude certain plugins](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131394/how-do-i-exclude-plugins-from-getting-automatically-updated/131404#131404). Also, the update page in Wordpress tells you if auto updates are enabled. If it doesn't mention auto-updates, then use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/background-update-tester/) to learn why they're disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your site and server configuration support automatic updates with the [Background Update Tester plugin](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/10/26/new-plugin-background-update-tester/). From Nacin: "This plugin checks your site for compatibility and explains any problems."

Comment: Not updated since 2015, the times of wordpress ~ 4.1.

Comment: Downvoted because of @kubanczyk's very pertinent comment.