# How do I set a custom WordPress update repository?

Tags: core, repository

I'm co-authoring a white paper on utilising WordPress as a foundation for a web-app, I would like to change the repository that the core WordPress updates from, the latest additions of automatic updates in 3.7 are very nice, but how would I go about pointing some installations at a custom server repository of mine? I understand the principals behind custom plugin and theme repositories, but updating the core is a necessity.

I think that it queries api.wordpress.org, but what about the server-side code? Is this available anywhere?

If this isn't possible, how would I go about having my WordPress core fetch updates through another manner? Using git/SVN on these other installs won't be an option unfortunately and neither will deploying to them directly, it needs to be via the internal WordPress protocols as this whole paper is about showing that WordPress is a very solid foundation to build upon.

I guess you could consider this a custom fork of WordPress aimed at office usage.

Thanks in advance,
Hamual

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  If you don't want WordPress to auto-update, you can turn that off in the `wp-config.php` file -- [see this Q/A for more details](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120081/how-do-i-configure-automatic-updates-in-wordpress-3-7).  It's not a good idea, IMHO, to send users to a non-official site to download WordPress.

Comment: What we're trying to accomplish for the white paper and tutorial series is being able to use WordPress for the basis of a self-hosted web app that is edited far beyond what WordPress is considered to be in terms of UI and usage and that includes getting updates from servers other than those of the official WordPress ones for when elements of the app are updated. The usage scenario is a modern take on an office intranet system with an accompanying iPhone app, and obviously with the core part of WordPress edited, any updates to the core other than from a specific server wouldn't be too good.

Comment: Have you seen [Filter any HTTP request URI?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72529/73) This is how I would change the URL.

Comment: Also have a look at the `WP_Upgrader` and `WP_Automatic_Updater` classes

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the solutions provided in this blog, which includes a plugin server: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2013/03/12/wordpress-update-server/ Btw. When & where will the whitepaper be available? It sounds interesting. Edit: made url more specific