# Error checking when future updates are automatic

Tags: plugins, updates

When WordPress 3.8 released, I upgraded most of my sites. However, there is a nagging question in the back of my mind.

Will the WP auto update process check whether all the plug-ins are working with the update or will it proceed without that check?

In which case how do I stop the auto updates for sites which I know are having plug-ins which may not work with the later versions of WP.

Answer (score 2):

> how do I stop the auto updates for sites which I know ...etc

Following code at least should prevent auto updating:(add in wp-config.php) 
`define( 'AUTOMATIC_UPDATER_DISABLED', true );`

Here you find an (imho) handy explanation about the how to handle in which cases:
[Chip Bennets "readers digest"](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120081/how-do-i-configure-automatic-updates-in-wordpress-3-7)

Another nice informative page is following: [The definitive guide to disabling auto updates](http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/10/25/the-definitive-guide-to-disabling-auto-updates-in-wordpress-3-7/)

And ofcourse some [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Disabling_Automatic_Background_Updates) information about the issue.

Comment: Charles said it nicely. I just want to add one more thing, is: Automatic Update only do updates from any development version. For any stable update, it won't update automatically. Like, it will update from v.3.7 to v.3.7.1, but it won't update from 3.7 to 3.8, because it's stable release. :)