# What is a good way to test that plugin upgrades have completed properly?

Tags: plugins, upgrade, testing

I'm working to automate plugin upgrades across all my WordPress installs. Part of that process is making sure the plugins upgraded correctly, didn't introduce errors and don't cause new conflicts with other plugins.

Is there a way to check that plugins have upgraded correctly afterwards?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Do I Configure Automatic Updates in WordPress 3.7?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120081/how-do-i-configure-automatic-updates-in-wordpress-3-7)

Comment: It's not at all a duplicate. I'm not asking how to automate, I'm asking how to confirm a plugin update has completed correctly. This is more of a testing question than an automation. It would be just as helpful for someone performing a manual update of their plugins.

Comment: off-topic as it is not wordpress specific. Your questiong is basically "How do I verify that my site still functions correctly after I make a change to the code" to which the only good answer is to test your site at a test enviroment before deploying it to your live server.

Comment: I'm looking for an automated way to test. Yes, a testing environment is a good place to test but I still need an *automated* way to test in that environment.